# How to assign single quote to date and time in dynamic query using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic query where I need pass date and time as parameter to stored procedure.

**Example**:

Creating Function:

```
create procedure test @dt varchar(10),@tm varchar(12)
as
    print @dt
    print @tm
go
```

Calling Function:

```
EXEC Test @dt = '2014-01-01', @tm = '10:00:00.000'
```

Result:

```
2014-01-01
10:00:00.000
```

**Question**: How to put resulted date and time in single quote?

**Expected Result**

```
'2014-01-01'
'10:00:00.000'
```

Comment: print ''''+ @dt + ''''

Comment: Why are you working with strings for these when SQL Server has data types for dealing specifically with dates, times and datetimes? Even if you're creating a dynamic query, you can pass *parameters* to dynamic queries using the appropriate data types.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yes! Exactly. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create procedure test @dt varchar(10),@tm varchar(12)
as
    print ''''+@dt+''''
    print ''''+@tm+''''
go

EXEC Test @dt = '2014-01-01', @tm = '10:00:00.000'
```